# Rviz: Message Filter dropping message: frame 'base_link' at time 47.226 for reason 'discarding message because the queue is full'

Tags: ros2, rviz, tf2-ros

Initially I would like to write a simple controller for an skid steer robot with the possibility of later use with slam_tooolbox. I'm trying to write my odometry publisher, for later use with slam_toolbox. Took the example from the ROS2 tf2 tutorial to create the publisher, but the publisher written this way doesn't work because when I select odom as the "Fixed frame" and Rviz gives an error about no transformation from odom -> base_link. After that I linked my publisher to the simulation time, but now I get an error:
`Message Filter dropping message: frame 'base_link' at time 47.226 for reason 'discarding message because the queue is full'`

I tried to make an analogy with diff_driver_controller, but I couldn't make sense of it

My state_publisher:

```py
from math import sin, cos, pi
import rclpy
from rclpy.node import Node
from rclpy.qos import QoSProfile
from geometry_msgs.msg import Quaternion
from rosgraph_msgs.msg import Clock
from sensor_msgs.msg import JointState
from builtin_interfaces.msg import Time
from nav_msgs.msg import Odometry
from tf2_ros import TransformBroadcaster, TransformStamped

class StatePublisher(Node):

    def __init__(self):
        rclpy.init()
        super().__init__('state_publisher')

        qos_profile = QoSProfile(depth=10)
        self.odomPub = self.create_publisher(Odometry, 'odom', qos_profile)

        # self.timeSub = self.create_subscription(Clock, 'clock', self.get_clock_time, 10)

        self.broadcaster = TransformBroadcaster(self)
        self.nodeName = self.get_name()
        self.get_logger().info("{0} started".format(self.nodeName))
        # self.clock_time = Time()
        # self.clock_time.sec = 0
        # self.clock_time.nanosec = 0
        degree = pi / 180.0
        loop_rate = self.create_rate(30)

        # robot state
        tilt = 0.
        tinc = degree
        swivel = 0.
        angle = 0.
        height = 0.
        hinc = 0.005
        try:
            while rclpy.ok():
                rclpy.spin_once(self)
                self.update()
                loop_rate.sleep()
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            pass
    
    def get_clock_time(self,msg):
        self.clock_time = msg.clock

    def update(self):

        # message declarations
        odom_trans = TransformStamped()
        odom_trans.header.frame_id = 'odom'
        odom_trans.child_frame_id = 'base_link'


        now = self.get_clock().now()
        # update transform

        odom_trans.header.stamp = now.to_msg()
        odom_trans.transform.translation.x = 0.
        odom_trans.transform.translation.y = 0.0
        odom_trans.transform.translation.z = 0.0
        odom_trans.transform.rotation = euler_to_quaternion(0, 0, 0) # roll,pitch,ya
        # send the joint state and transfor
        self.broadcaster.sendTransform(odom_trans)
        
        odom = Odometry()
        odom.header.stamp = now.to_msg()
        odom.header.frame_id = 'odom'
        odom.pose.pose.position.x = 0.0
        odom.pose.pose.position.y = 0.0
        odom.pose.pose.position.z = 0.0
        odom.pose.pose.orientation = euler_to_quaternion(0, 0, 0)
        odom.child_frame_id = 'base_link'
        odom.twist.twist.linear.x = 0.0
        odom.twist.twist.linear.y = 0.0
        odom.twist.twist.angular.z = 0.0
        # This will adjust as needed per iteration
        self.odomPub.publish(odom)
        #self.get_logger().info("UPDATE_END")

    def spin(self):
        loop_rate = self.create_rate(30)
        self.get_logger().info("SPIN")
        while rclpy.ok():
            
            self.get_logger().info("IN")
            self.update()

            loop_rate.sleep()
            self.get_logger().info("AFTER_SLEEP")
        


def euler_to_quaternion(roll, pitch, yaw):
    qx = sin(roll/2) * cos(pitch/2) * cos(yaw/2) - cos(roll/2) * sin(pitch/2) * sin(yaw/2)
    qy = cos(roll/2) * sin(pitch/2) * cos(yaw/2) + sin(roll/2) * cos(pitch/2) * sin(yaw/2)
    qz = cos(roll/2) * cos(pitch/2) * sin(yaw/2) - sin(roll/2) * sin(pitch/2) * cos(yaw/2)
    qw = cos(roll/2) * cos(pitch/2) * cos(yaw/2) + sin(roll/2) * sin(pitch/2) * sin(yaw/2)
    return Quaternion(x=qx, y=qy, z=qz, w=qw)

def main():
    node = StatePublisher()
    # loop_rate = node.create_rate(30)
    # try:
    #     while rclpy.ok():
    #         rclpy.spin_once(node)
    #         node.update()
    #         loop_rate.sleep()
    # except KeyboardInterrupt:
    #     node.get_logger().info("LOX")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

My launch file:

```py
import os
from ament_index_python.packages import get_package_share_directory
from launch import LaunchDescription
from launch.actions import DeclareLaunchArgument
from launch.actions import IncludeLaunchDescription, TimerAction
from launch.conditions import IfCondition
from launch.launch_description_sources import PythonLaunchDescriptionSource
from launch.substitutions import LaunchConfiguration, PythonExpression
from launch.substitutions import ThisLaunchFileDir


from launch_ros.actions import Node
import xacro


def generate_launch_description():

    # Specify the name of the package and path to xacro file within the package
    pkg_name = 'beginning'
    file_subpath = 'urdf/rover_1.xacro'

    urdf_tutorial_path = get_package_share_directory(pkg_name)
    default_rviz_config_path = os.path.join(urdf_tutorial_path, 'rviz', 'urdf1.rviz')

    # Use xacro to process the file
    xacro_file = os.path.join(get_package_share_directory(pkg_name),file_subpath)
    robot_description_raw = xacro.process_file(xacro_file).toxml()

    
    world_path = LaunchConfiguration('world')
    world_path_declare = DeclareLaunchArgument('world', default_value='',description='World to open')

    # Configure the node
    node_robot_state_publisher = Node(
        package='robot_state_publisher',
        executable='robot_state_publisher',
        output='screen',
        parameters=[{'robot_description': robot_description_raw,
        'use_sim_time': True}] # add other parameters here if required
    )

    gui = DeclareLaunchArgument('gui', default_value='true',
                              description='Set to "false" to run headless.')

    server = DeclareLaunchArgument('server', default_value='true',
                              description='Set to "false" not to run gzserver.')
    
    delay = DeclareLaunchArgument('delay', default_value='0')


    # TF

    node_odom_state_publisher = Node(
        package='beginning',
        executable='state_publisher',
        name='state_publisher',
        output='screen',
        parameters=[{'use_sim_time': True}]
    )




    # GAZEBO
    gazebo_params_path = os.path.join(get_package_share_directory(pkg_name),'config','gazebo_params.yaml')

    include_server = IncludeLaunchDescription(PythonLaunchDescriptionSource([ThisLaunchFileDir(), '/gzserver.launch.py']),
                                                condition=IfCondition(LaunchConfiguration('server')),
                                                launch_arguments={'world': world_path, 'extra_gazebo_args': '--verbose'}.items()) #'extra_gazebo_args': '--ros-args --params-file ' + gazebo_params_path 
    include_client = IncludeLaunchDescription(PythonLaunchDescriptionSource([ThisLaunchFileDir(), '/gzclient.launch.py']),#'params_file': gazebo_params_path,
                                                condition=IfCondition(LaunchConfiguration('gui'))) #,
                                                # launch_arguments={'extra_gazebo_args': '--ros-args --params-file ' + gazebo_params_path }.items())

    print('CHECKPOINT1')

    spawn_entity = Node(package='gazebo_ros', executable='spawn_entity.py',
                    arguments=['-topic', 'robot_description',
                                '-entity', 'my_bot',
                                '-z','5'],
                    output='screen')
    
    joint_state_publisher = Node(
        package='joint_state_publisher',
        executable='joint_state_publisher',
    )

    # RVIZ
    
    rviz = Node(
        package='rviz2',
        executable='rviz2',
        output='screen',
        arguments=['-d', default_rviz_config_path],
    )

    timer_spawn = TimerAction(period = '0', actions=[spawn_entity])

    # CONTROL

    left_wheel_1_spawner = Node(
        package="controller_manager",
        executable="spawner.py",
        arguments=["left_wheel_1"],
    )

    diff_drive_spawner = Node(
        package="controller_manager",
        executable="spawner.py",
        arguments=["diff_cont"],
    )

    joint_broad_spawner = Node(
        package="controller_manager",
        executable="spawner.py",
        arguments=["joint_state_broadcaster"],
    )



    # Run the node
    return LaunchDescription([
        world_path_declare,
        gui,
        server,
        include_server,
        include_client,
        node_robot_state_publisher,
        node_odom_state_publisher,
        left_wheel_1_spawner,
        # diff_drive_spawner,
        joint_broad_spawner,
        timer_spawn,
        rviz,
        # joint_state_publisher
    ])
```

I haven't found any good guides on writing my odometry publisher or map publisher using tf. Maybe there is another way to do it, please guide me.